# MP4 video is playing only the sound with no video in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html5-video

I try to play an mp4 video in IE9, which has 237 Mo size, i can hear the sound but no video is displayed, my file is conformed to html5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) and the following is how i implement the video tag (all works fine in chrome):

```
<video id="video" src="videos/myVideo.mp4" type='video/mp4' preload controls>
      Your brwoser doesn't seems to support video
    </video>
```

I got a white screen with the sound, but no video.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 9 has some trouble running the HTML5 video player (as it does with a lot of things). Referencing [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp), I think that it would be wise to encode your video file across all filetypes to allow for maximum support cross browser. If you can, try to use a video service like YouTube or Vimeo because they take care of all the encoding for you, but if you need to do it yourself, check out the HTML5 docs on how to use multiple encoded files.

Comment: Hi, would you mean that i need to have the video file in multiple formats? (mp4, ogg, etc.).

Comment: To allow cross browser support you would need multiple formats which is usually why video services are a lot simpler for what you need to do.

Comment: but MP4 container, with H264 video and AAC audio, *is* supposed to work in IE (actually, as of today, it should be the only supported container among HTML5 video sources for IE)

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that the mp4 needs to be encode using the H.264 codec in IE. I haven't confirmed this because I'm having problems playing my video in IE9 too. You can use MPEG Streamclip to convert your video file, at least on a Mac.